# How to ignore corrupted rows in pandas to_sql

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I save pandas dataframe to postgres db table using [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). If one of rows is of incorrect format, psycopg2.DataError is raised and whole dataframe  does not get saved. I tried to catch the error and save rows one by one with chunksize = 1, but the result is the same. How to ignore corrupted rows? This is the code I use:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/db_name')
df = pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, error_bad_lines=False)
for chunk in df:
    try:
        chunk.to_sql(TABLE_NAME, con=engine,)
    except:
        chunk.to_sql(TABLE_NAME, con=engine, chunksize=1)
```

I expect to_sql to ignore only corrupted rows and save all other. Is it achievable? The current workaround is to split the dataframe into smaller parts and save them one by one. It is expensive though.

Comment: Have you tried with a greate chunk size, i.e., ```chunksize = 1000```?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a similar approach as yours, but with the addition of exceptions:

```
def insert_data(df, table_name):
    try: 
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error) 
        df.to_sql(table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=1000)
```